# How to scroll down the window from by vertical scroll down in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vertical-scrolling

How to scroll down the window form with the help of vertical scroll in C#. When I scroll window form should move down with the help of vertical scroll down.

How to do and what to do in C# for both while designing and while running?

Comment: Just set focus to the last control

Comment: if you can use FlowLayoutPanel, you can set focus to the Last control that you added it... can you use it?

Comment: Define "form should move down". Scrolling logic is already implemented in Winforms, it's just a matter of getting the focus on right control.

Comment: For which shall i keep focus to the last control is it for window form or vertical scroll i had seen focus option but it doesn't exists @SebastianL

Comment: its not a property but a method. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to scroll to the `lbl_txt`, you can do this:

```
this.AutoScroll = true;
lbl.Focus();
```

*`lbl_txt` could be any control*

Comment: it works while i am running the application.But what shall i do for while designing Form3.cs[Design].i need to insert 50 + labels while designing. @ Mehdi Khademloo

Comment: @user2837291 set the control's AutoScroll property to true in the property panel.

Comment: set the form's AutoScroll Property in the property panel ;)

Comment: Done But no Effect @nevets

Comment: Done But no Effect while drag and dropping the labels in window from not scrolling down @MehdiKhademloo

Comment: Come on... Drag a control to your form and in running-time reduce your form size. and then, you can see the SrollBar

Comment: Use UpVote if your question is answered by this answer